# Extracting specific columns in numpy array by condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a homework assignment to extract a 2-dimensional numpy array out of another 2-dimensional np array by choosing specific columns by condition (not by range).

So I have an array `A` with shape `(3, 50000)`. I am trying to get a new array with shape `(3, x)` for some `x < 50000 with the original columns of`A`that satisfy the third cell in the column is`-0.4 < z < 0.1`.

For example if:

```
A = [[1,2,3],[2,0.5,0],[9,-2,-0.2],[0,0,0.5]]
```

I wish to have back:

```
B = [[2,0.5,0],[9,-2,-0.2]
```

I have tried to make a bool 1 rank array that holds true on the columns I want, and to some how combine between the two. The problem it's output is 1 rank array which is not what I am looking for. And I got some ValueErrors..

```
bool_idx = (-0.4 < x_y_z[2] < 0.1)
```

This code made some troubles:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I can do it with some loops but NumPy got so many beautiful function I am sure I am missing something here..

Comment: Can you share what you tried ?

Comment: What I try my methos it returns a 1-rank array.. I tried to use x_y_z[bool_idx]
when bool_idx is 1-rank array with true on the right columns and false on the ones I dont want.. but it won't work like that..

Comment: Can you show a full runnable example please?

Comment: What do you mean by full runnable example? What I showed with A and B is not clear enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python, the expression `-0.4 < x_y_z[2] < 0.1` is roughly equivalent to `-0.4 < x_y_z[2] and x_y_z[2] < 0.1`. The `and` operator decides the truth value of each part of the expression by converting it into a bool. Unlike Python lists and tuples, numpy arrays do not support the conversion.

The correct way to specify the condition is with bitwise `&` (which is unambiguous and non-short-circuiting), rather than the implicit `and` (which short circuits and is ambiguous in this case):

```
condition = ((x_y_z[2, :] > - 0.4) & (x_y_z[2, :] < 0.1))
```

`condition` is a boolean mask that selects the columns you want. You can select the rows with a simple slice:

```
selection = x_y_z[:, condition]
```

Comment: Yesit works! Thank you so much! I dont understand tho what is the meaning of [2, :]. The second row at any column?